# Overwriting property in Object.observe()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-objects, ecmascript-harmony, object.observe

I want to use Chrome's experimental [Object.observe()](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfOh-J-9BY0) in order to overwrite all functions being set on the object:

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8zYS/1/)

```
var obj = {};

Object.observe(obj, function (changes) {
    changes.forEach(function (data) {
        if ((data.type == "new" || data.type == "updated") &&
            typeof data.object[data.name] == "function" &&
            typeof data.object[data.name].isWrapper == "undefined") {

            data.object[data.name] = function () {
            };
            data.object[data.name].isWrapper = true;

        }

    });
});

obj.helloWorld = function () {
    console.log("helloWorld() was called");
};
obj.helloWorld();
```

Unfortunately, the console still displays *"helloWorld() was called"*. Is it actually possible to overwrite the currently changed value in an object observer?

Since this is only an experiment (no production code!), I appreciate any kind of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot really solve the problem at hand.
While you can overwrite changed values again in the observer, [the observer is only executed **asynchronously**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aobserve_overview), unless `Object.deliverChangeRecords` is explicitly called, so it is only executed after `obj.helloWorld()` was already called in the same turn it was defined.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8zYS/2/) to show just that:

```
var obj = {};

function obs(changes) {
    changes.forEach(function (data) {
        if ((data.type == "new" || data.type == "updated") &&
            typeof data.object[data.name] == "function" &&
            typeof data.object[data.name].isWrapper == "undefined") {

            data.object[data.name] = function () {
                console.log("intercepted", data.name);
            };
            data.object[data.name].isWrapper = true;

        }

    });
}

Object.observe(obj, obs);

obj.helloWorld = function () {
    console.log("helloWorld() was called");
};
// Will call the original function, as changes are not yet delivered.
obj.helloWorld();

Object.deliverChangeRecords(obs); 
// Will call the intercepted function, as the changes were explicitly delivered synchronously.
obj.helloWorld();

obj.helloWorld2 = function () {
    console.log("helloWorld2() was called");
};
// Will call the intercepted function, as first the changes will be delivered (end of turn) and only then the timeout callback will be called.
setTimeout(function() { obj.helloWorld2(); }, 0);
```

Not entirely sure if the `setTimeout` bits are implicitly mandated by the spec proposal or just an implementation detail, though.

Since there is no way to observe any changes immediately and synchronously without the modifying code explicitly executing `Object.deliverChangeRecords`, this API isn't really suited for what you're trying to achieve, at least when it comes to the current spec proposal.

A viable alternative to `Object.observe` might be [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which is actually meant to do things like this and which IIRC is also available in Chrome (with experimental harmony features turned on).
Here is [a fiddle using `Proxy`](http://jsfiddle.net/w8zYS/3/).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Regarding the term "current processing turn (or “Microtask”)" (found on your linked MDN page), do you have an official description of what a "microtask" is at hand? I only found some forum and mailing list posts which describe a specific "queue" containing the so-called microtasks.

Comment: Not really having an official description at hand (if there is any). In short it just means, that the changes won't be delivered until the currently running code is done running. So the normal behavior unless specified otherwise. For example if you run `var i; setTimeout(function() { i = 2000000; }, 0); for(i = 0; i < 100000; ++i);` the timeout callback won't be run before the current execution context (Draft 8.3) will be done, i.e. after the for loop is done. And if `i` was `Object.observe()d`, the observer won't be called until the for loop is done, as well.

Comment: Damn, looked in the wrong place. See the [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops)...

Comment: Thanks for your research and explanation, I'll have a look at those links! You deserve your bounty (in 21 hrs.) ;)

Comment: Got curious if Chrome supports enough of Proxy, and it seems it does... well kinda. See updated answer. (I skipped implementing `fix`, though).